# Batch script to join matching records in .csv file

Tags: csv, for-loop, batch-file, findstr

I have a `.csv` file with 4 fields.

Field 1, 2, and 3 are text boxes

Field 4 is a number such as 1, 2, 3, etc.

There are multiple instances of field 1, 2, and 3 being the exact same for multiple records. In these instances I want to remove all but one of these records and add the number from the other (now removed) records to the end of the one remaining record.

To try and give an example:

I have

```
A,B,C,1
A,B,C,2
A,B,C,3
D,E,F,1
D,E,F,3
```

I Want

```
A,B,C,"1,2,3"
D,E,F,"1,3"
```

I have been looking into solutions for hours at this point and have gotten next to nowhere (I am completely new to scripting) as far as I can tell, I probably need to be using a `for /f` command or a `findstr` command, with certain conditions, but I'm really struggling on where to even start.

Comment: The delimiter in your `csv` is `<space><slash><space>`?

Comment: No, apologies, the delimiter should be the default delimiter when converting an excel doc to a csv, which I believe is a comma (,)

Comment: Double check. Some languages use `;` instead.

Comment: TBF, if your final column is using commas, I'd prefer to see the delimiter changed to a tab or a semicolon too. Does the order of the records in the resulting CSV matter?

Comment: I checked and it is currently set to comma (,) changing it to semicolon may be a good call in that case since I do want comma's in the final column. The order of the records is not important as long as they are all listed.

Comment: So if you look at a sorted copy of the file, _(use the `sort.exe` utility)_, you'll see that it is easier for the code to, deal with the fourth field changes, when it just has to check the first three fields in a record, against the first three fields in the previous record. This may not be necessary, but on a large file, would probably be quicker/more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims=," %%a in (t.csv) do (
   set "_%%a,%%b,%%c=!_%%a,%%b,%%c!%%d,"

)
(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_=" %%a in ('set _') do (
  set "D=%%b
  echo %%a,"!D:~0,-1!"
))>output.csv
```

The first loop gathers the data (adding column 4 to a variable named as "column1 to 3".
The second loop prints the variable names (= "column 1 to 3") plus the collected "columns 4", while removing the last comma and adding the quotes and redirecting the whole loops output to a file.

Output with your sample data:

```
A,B,C,"1,2,3"
D,E,F,"1,3"
```

Comment: Note: The specific possible characters in your first three fields, and the combined character lengths of those fields, may be problematic if trying to create variables using their content.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74435774.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "field1="

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('sort "%filename1%"') DO CALL :compare %%e
)
IF DEFINED field1 ECHO %field1%,%field2%,%field3%,"%field4:~1%"
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:compare
IF "%1,%2,%3" neq "%field1%,%field2%,%field3%" (
 IF DEFINED field1 ECHO %field1%,%field2%,%field3%,"%field4:~1%"
 SET "field1=%1"
 SET "field2=%2"
 SET "field3=%3"
 SET "field4="
)
SET "field4=%field4%,%4"

goto :eof
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Read each line and `call` the `:compare` subroutine with the entire line as parameters. Since the data is comma-separated, each field becomes a parameter.

Check whether the first 3 parameters strung together match the last-reported fields1..3. If not, we have a new combination so report the last combination and initialise a new one.

Then accumulate the new field4.

`field1` is initialised to *nothing* and can be used as a flag to indicate whether the first line has been processed.

The data is sorted by the `sort` command (add the undocumented `/unique` switch if the source data may contain identical lines) so the data will always be presented to `:compare` grouped by field1..3.

The `for` will finish at the end of the data, but the very last item will not have been reported, so it's necessary to perform the `echo` one more time.

Fields4 will be accumulated with a leading <kbd>,</kbd> so we simply skip that character when `echo` ing.

The `for` and final `if` are enclosed in parentheses forming a `code block` which allows the `echo`es to be redirected to a file.